# bounding a certain quantity

Tags: inequality

Is there a way to bound the following quantity
$$
|\sqrt{a_n - b_n} - \sqrt{a-b}|
$$
with an expression composed of the expressions $a_n-a$ and $b_n -b$?

Comment: Is using $a_n + a$ and $b_n + b$ ok? Because that's possible by squaring and using AM-GM inequality.

Comment: I actually need the differences $a_n - a$ and $b_n - b$ on the right side of the resulting inequality.

Comment: If this is about sequences then try multiplying top and bottom by the "conjugate" $|\sqrt{a_n - b_n} + \sqrt{a-b}|$ and use the convergence of $a_n$ and $b_n$ to bound the denominator for sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

It is bounded by $\frac {|a_n-a|+|b_b-a|} {\sqrt {|a-b|}}$. You get this multiplying numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{a_n-b_n}+\sqrt {a-b}$.